# How to check if find or findBy returns Null?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities

- `Client`
- `Info`

with a one-to-one-unidirectional relationship, as a `Client` can have none or one `Info`.

I am trying to check if `Client` already has `Info` with this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$check = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Info")>findBy(array(
    'client_id' => $id, 
));
```

Note that `$id` would be the client id I am already passing as a parameter and have access to. The question is what sort of data would `$check` would be so I can be able to verify it as shown below:

```
if ($check ??..) {
    //..do this
} else { 
    //.. do that
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is that simple. Use `findOneBy()`, which returns either an entity or `null` if the entity can not be found:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$info = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Info")->findOneBy([
    'client_id' => $id,
]);

if ($info) {
    // manipulate existing info
} else {
    // create new info
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions